# ansible - Modify line closest to [string] in file

Tags: regex, replace, ansible

Struggling to get a play working.If I have a file such as:

```
[host]:
  port: 8080
  name2
[city]
  port: 8080
```

How could I write an ansible module that modifies the first occurrence of port: 8080 to port: 80 from the [host] string?

I have tried to insert after but so far can only get it to add a second port: 80 above the port: 8080. Any thoughts on how to search for a string then replace the first occurence under that string using ansible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace between two specified expressions [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#:%7E:text=-%20name%3A%20replace%20between%20the%20expressions%20(requires%20ansible%20%3E%3D%202.4))

```yaml
  - name: Replace between the expressions (requires Ansible >= 2.4)
    ansible.builtin.replace:
      path: file.yml
      after: 'host'
      before: 'city'
      regexp: '8080'
      replace: '80'
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the entire file so there's only one replacement:

```yaml
- replace:
    path: <your-file-path>
    regexp: '8080([\s\S]*)'
    replace: '80\1'
```

This works by matching `8080` but capturing (as group `1`) the rest of the file that follows, thanks to `[\s\S]` matching every character (importantly,  including newlines).

The replacement puts but `80` and the rest of the file via `\1` - the back-reference to group `1`.

See [live demo of regex](https://rubular.com/r/TiKNuJWQddWmvq).

Comment: That would also replace the second 8080 in file, if it's executed for a second time

Comment: @Khaled I'm not an ansible user, but the regexp consumes the whole file, and having consumed the whole file, would it execute again?

Comment: Thanks Bohemian for your answer. @IT_User didn't mention if it would be executed again, but it doesn't make sense to write a playbook that runs only one time. Quote from the official documentation: Ansible Playbooks offer a repeatable, re-usable, simple configuration…

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks for this. While it worked I went with the other answer so my playbook was repeatable. I Used replace before but must have glossed over the documentation for the before/after piece. Thanks!